# REST API data display in admin grid Magento 2.4.4

Tags: api, rest-api, magento2.4.4, custom-admin-grid

How does REST API show data in Admin Grid ?

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

These are the some useful links that may help you :

[Create a REST API to get the data from the custom table in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/359420/create-a-rest-api-to-get-the-data-from-the-custom-table-in-magento-2)

[Magento 2 Api/Data, When To Create It?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/245866/magento-2-api-data-when-to-create-it)

[magento2, REST API how correctly return data](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/319274/magento2-rest-api-how-correctly-return-data)

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/creat-a-ui-form-in-magento-2.html

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/ui-components/concepts/data-source/

Comment: Thank you for your answer. +1